# Property of Colon Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $J_1,J_2$ be ideals of a commutative ring $A$ with identity. Then $(I:J_1):J_2= I:J_1J_2$.

I need some hints in showing this result. Following is what I have tried so far. I am quite new to Ring Theory:

Let $y \in (I:J_1):J_2 \implies yJ_2 \subseteq I:J_1$. Then for any $x \in yJ_2, x $ is of the form $x=yj_2$ for some $j_2 \in J_2$. Since $xJ_1 \subseteq I \implies yj_2J_1 \subseteq yJ_2J_1\subseteq I$. Hence $y \in I:J_1J_2$.

Conversely, let $y \in I:J_1J_2$. Then $yJ_1J_2 \subseteq I$.I don't know as how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can you show $yJ_2 \subset I:J_1$?

Comment: @Pacifism I see now. Thank you,